# zend framework: comments form issue

Tags: forms, zend-framework, authentication, frameworks, comments

I have a table comments like this:

```
Com_ID | Com_Content | Com_Date | Book_ID| User_ID
```

I can get everything but `User_ID`. I have already storage `User_ID` in `Zend_Auth` and I can view it on screen but I don't know how to get it to my from.

For example I can get `Com_Date` in my `IndexController` like this:

```
public function CommentAction()
{           
    $Com_Date = new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()');
    ...
```

So can I do the same thing with `User_ID` and how to do it? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

An identity that has been authenticated using `Zend_Auth` can be retrieved in the following way:

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
    // Identity exists; get it
    $identity = $auth->getIdentity();
}
```

Hope this is what you mean.

Comment: i found the solution here:  $auth=  Zend_Session::namespaceGet("Zend_Auth");
            $user=$auth["storage"];
            $username=$user->username;